# Rename and Set a network printer as the default printer in powershell

Tags: powershell

printers need to be added due to print server migration. printers are renamed. need to set the default renamed printer. need help

```
$oldprinters=Get-Printer -Name "\\eesfs2\eep*"
foreach ($oldprinter in $oldprinters){
$newprinter=$oldprinter.name.split("\")[-1] -replace "EEP","RUSP"
Add-Printer -ConnectionName "\\rus0005\$newprinter"
}
```

Comment: Try `(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).SetDefaultPrinter("\\rus0005\$newprinter")`

Comment: a user can have many printers. I need to configure by default exactly the one that was (after rename).

Comment: well you have to get the old default printer from them first then...
take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639541/get-default-printer-remotely/20644755

Answer (score 0):

```
$OldPrinters = gwmi win32_printer | where {$_.Name -like "\\eesfs2\eep*"}
foreach ($oldprinter in $Oldprinters){
$newprinter=$oldprinter.name.split("\")[-1] -replace "EEP","RUSP"
$a="\\rus0005\$newprinter"
Add-Printer -ConnectionName $a
if ($oldprinter.Default) {
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).SetDefaultPrinter($a)
}
}
```